# Handling One to One foreign key relationships - LightSwitch

Tags: foreign-key-relationship, one-to-one, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am currently trying to add a one to one foreign key relationship in LightSwitch. It is between an ID and a username. Ideally I would be able to show the username wherever the related ID is displayed. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one to one relationships are not supported. What is supported is one to one or zero mappings. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff852044.aspx#Multiplicity